Get a single row in a tuple-indexed DataFrame
I have a pandas DataFrame:
>>> f = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"r0":{"c0":1,"c1":2},("r",1):{"c0":3,"c1":4}},orient="index")
        c0      c1
r0      1       2
(r, 1)  3       4

I can get the 1st row:
>>> list(f.loc["r0"].items())
[('c0', 1), ('c1', 2)]

but not the second row because f.loc[("r",1)] raises KeyError.
I suppose I can do
>>> list(f.loc[[("r",1)]].iloc[0].items())
[('c0', 3), ('c1', 4)]

but this is unspeakably ugly.
What is the right way?
PS. No, I do not want to use MultiIndex here.

Try using cross-section to get values from multiple indices.
list(f.xs(("r", 1)).items())


You can probably do it in the following way:
list(f.iloc[1].items())


I want to access my rows using the index.
